# Aiohttp : How to have a function called after each of my handlers requests are processed to log info?

Tags: python, aiohttp

In aiohttp I want to add some logging and measure processing time for every handler functions, but can't find the right way to do so.

I'm looking for something similar to tornado.web.Application log_function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a logging middleware, see https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-debugtoolbar project for inspiration.
The debug toolbar measures web handler's execution time along with collecting many other useful information.

Comment: see also [https://github.com/underyx/aiohttp-sentry](https://github.com/underyx/aiohttp-sentry)